# mysqli_select_db() ERROR, Database couln't connect

Tags: php

Hi I'm new to PHP and i coded a php page and created a database. I tried to connect db but it's not connecting.

```
<?php
$uname = "root";
$pwd = "";
$hostn = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$mysqlconn = mysqli_connect($hostn, $uname, $pwd)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$dbselect = mysqli_select_db("dataforuse",$mysqlconn)
  or die("Could not select dataforuse");
mysql_close($mysqlconn);
?>
```

[image: This is what i get]

Comment: you are mixing mysql and mysqli

Comment: $dbselect = mysqli_select_db($mysqlconn,"dataforuse")  connection variable then database name ..try this

Comment: Remove `mysql_close($mysqlconn);` its a TOTALLY different API and they dont mix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Try to debug and echo bugs in connection with `mysqli_error()` `function`.

```
    $uname = "root";
    $pwd = "";
    $hostn = "localhost"; 

    //connection to the database

        $mysqlconn = mysqli_connect($hostn, $uname, $pwd) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

or 

      $mysqlconn = mysqli_connect($hostn, $uname, $pwd , $database) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are mixing mysql and mysqli**

You have to replace

```
/connection to the database
$mysqlconn = mysqli_connect($hostn, $uname, $pwd)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$dbselect = mysqli_select_db("dataforuse",$mysqlconn)
  or die("Could not select dataforuse");
```

With this code

```
$mysqlconn = mysqli_connect($hostn, $uname, $pwd,"dataforuse")
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
```

Answer (score 0):

connection variable then database name ..try this

```
$dbselect = mysqli_select_db($mysqlconn,"dataforuse");
```

and mysql close should be like this

```
   mysqli_close($mysqlconn);
```

**dont mix mysql with mysqli**

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
<?php
$uname = "root";
$pwd = "";
$hostn = "localhost";
$dbname = "dataforuse";

$conn = new mysqli($hostn, $uname, $pwd, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

This will solve Your Problem